# Do Universe and Dimension mean the same thing?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In Rick and Morty tv show, they keep using the word “dimension” more than the word “universe”.

Do both these words mean the same thing?

Comment: Hi, I have already put that link in the question comment. The question and answer use the words dimension and universe interchangeably but notwhere is it explicitly mentioned that they are the same. That's why I asked this question

Comment: Any information relevant to the question should appear in the body of the question. You can also explain there why the other question's answers don't answer this (ie. why it's not a duplicate) then this should, all being well, get opened again.